# Plotly Dash application doesn't running

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am attempting to run the following code from jupyter notebook:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    html.Div(children='Dash: A web application framework for Python.'),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

It produces the following:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

And when I click on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ , the page never loads

Comment: What happens if you try `app.run_server(debug=False)` ?

Comment: Doesn't work, this works when I'm running this code locally in my computer using Pycharm. But the error comes when I run it in the server of my company that use jupyter notebooks with Ngrok

Comment: Ah - are you running the notebook on a remote server? In that case `localhost` aka `127.0.0.1` will not be the same as `localhost` on your own computer.

Comment: Yes I'm using a remote server. What should I do?

Comment: In your browser, you should enter the IP of the remote server (instead of localhost).

Comment: How can I found that IP?

Comment: I came across this thread while trying ti figure how to run Dash app on server other than local.
I am using NGROK to make my local server public.
The local server get forwarded to this address host='13584e17.ngrok.io' which I’m not able to use in Dash says

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

This is the forwarded addess using NGROK:

Forwarding https://13584e17.ngrok.io -> 127.0.0.1:8081

Comment: I tried this code and doesn't work
import socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
app.run_server(debug=False, host=host, port =8050)